# Fetching posts from FaceBook Page and displaying on website

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

Could someone please let me know how I can fetch posts posted by the account owner on the wall. In my case, I need to fetch posts from the wall of our company facebook page.

I have tried using the Graph API to fetch the results, but I have trouble fetching the access token.

To get Access Token, I have used the code below:

```
public string GetAccessToken()
{
string params = string.Format("grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}", this.ApplicationId, this.ApplicationSecret);
FacebookResponse response = this.IssueRequest(RequestAction.POST, "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token", params);
if ((response.HttpResponseCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (response.JSON != string.Empty))
{
this.AccessToken = response.JSON.Split(new char[] { '=' })[1];
}
return this.AccessToken;
}
```

To get UserData, I have used below:

```
public string GetUserData(string UserId, UserConnection UC)
{
string uRL = string.Empty;
if (this.AccessToken != string.Empty)
{
uRL = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/{1}?access_token={2}", UserId, Common.GetStringValue(UC), this.AccessToken);
}
else
{
uRL = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/{1}", UserId, Common.GetStringValue(UC));
}
FacebookResponse response = this.IssueRequest(RequestAction.POST, uRL, string.Empty);
if ((response.HttpResponseCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) && (response.JSON != string.Empty))
{
return response.JSON;
}
return null;
}
```

In my code, I make call to the Graph API as below:

```
FacebookGraphApi fg = new FacebookGraphApi();
FacebookGraphApi.FacebookUserFeed[] Feed =
FacebookGraphApi.ParseUserFeed(fg.GetUserData(ApplicationId, FacebookGraphApi.UserConnection.FEED));

//Bind results to Repeater
rptFacebookFeed.DataSource = Feed;
rptFacebookFeed.DataBind();


The ParseUserFeed returns FacebookUserFeed[] array.
```

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: What is the problem? It'll be better to describe what is wrong with your code or errors you have.

Comment: @Juicy Scripter :It gives me a generic error, Object reference not set to an instance of an object.    It points to this particular line      FacebookGraphApi.FacebookUserFeed[] Feed =  FacebookGraphApi.ParseUserFeed(fg.GetUserData(ApplicationId, FacebookGraphApi.UserConnection.FEED));                                              I've put breakpoint on the above and it breaks there. My speculation is.. if the problem is with the GetUserData method call, where it's trying to get the returned object.